# Different package.json in Angular workspace

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm developing an application that has to run on desktop browsers and as apk/ipa on mobile.
For the mobile version I'm using Ionic but I would like to **not** use Ionic on the desktop version.

I would like to create 2 projects and a library in the same workspace:

- Library: contains all shared code (services, ui components, css, configs, ...)
- Project1: a vanilla Angular application that uses the **Library proj**
- Project2: a Ionic application for the mobile apps that uses the **Library proj**

but seems that Ionic needs an entire workspace, I can't figure out how to use it as a project of a vanilla workspace.
Am I right?

Thanks a lot